# Facebook events API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a page on facebook and i have created a number of events on it.

I also use those events in my mobile app.

But now the graph API shows events that i have already been to.

If you go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=jarnvags/events) you'll see it shows 4 events.

But the last 2 events from the bottom are the past events.

I have already added end date for them so that can't be the issue here.

What to do so that the graph API doesn't show those 2 events?

I don't want to remove them from facebook, but just want to hide it.

Please advice.

Comment: What hinders you from just throwing the events out that were in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict the data returned by facebook to show only the events created after a specific date using the `since` query parameter which accepts a unix timestamp.

So if you want events which are created after **8th of October 2012** or any other date, you can make a call with the `since` query parameter, In this case the unix timestamp of `08 Oct 2012 00:00:00 GMT` will be `1349654400`.

Now if we make a call with the `since` query parameter and the above unix timestamp, It'll return all the events created after **8th of October 2012**.

Here's a working call made on [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=jarnvags%2Fevents%3Fsince%3D1349654400) with the `since` query parameter.

In case if the above link does not work:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=jarnvags%2Fevents%3Fsince%3D1349654400
>
> **Path**: jarnvags/events?since=1349654400

Let me know if this helped you :)

**EDIT:**
Here's how to do it with [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20eid%2C%20name%2C%20description%2C%20pic_big%2C%20start_time%2C%20end_time%2C%20location%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20creator%20%3D%20109341359096369%20AND%20eid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20109341359096369%29%20AND%20start_time%20%3E%3D%20now%28%29%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time):

```
SELECT eid, name, description, pic_big, start_time, end_time, location FROM event WHERE creator = 109341359096369 AND eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 109341359096369) AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time
```

And here's how you should do it in PHP:

```
$pageID = '109341359096369';
$fql = 'SELECT eid, name, description, pic_big, start_time, end_time, location FROM event WHERE creator = ' . $pageID . ' AND eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = ' . $pageID . ') AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                           'method' => 'fql.query',
                           'query' => $fql,
                         ));
print_r($ret_obj);
```

Check out `event` table [FQL docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

**EDIT 2:** Just wanted to highlight the point made by [cpilko](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12809224/facebook-events-api/12809902#comment17326263_12809902) below in comments so people who see this answer in future could easily notice it, You don't have to convert the date to timestamp anymore, It works with just the date as well (`2012-10-08`).

And here's the [`Events Timezone Migration Note`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) quoted from facebook events doc:

> **[Events Timezone Migration Note](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)**
>
> Starting with the 'Events Timezone' migration, all event times are
>   always ISO-8601 formatted strings; the 'date_format' query string
>   modifier no longer has any effect. The following formats are now
>   returned, depending on the type of event:
>
> Date-only (e.g., '2012-07-04'): events that have a date but no
>   specific time yet. Precise-time (e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700'):
>   events that start at a particular point in time, in a specific offset
>   from UTC. This is the way new Facebook events keep track of time, and
>   allows users to view events in different timezones. Local-time
>   (deprecated, e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00'): legacy events that do not
>   have any timezone information. This format is deprecated, but
>   continues to be returned due to legacy events that are still in the
>   system.

Comment: You don't need to convert your date to a timestamp anymore. `jarnvags/events?since=2012-10-08` works just as well.

Comment: Oh that's great, Didn't knew it accepts date, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Ok i can understand this concept. But is there a way to make it using todays date?

Comment: I cant parse it with an access token         http://graph.facebook.com/jarnvags/events?since=2012-10-08?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBADR1jPcfggJ76VtEvtOHcZBj9AWmKnlPkhfbmmF40gZCmnZB9P5shAZADTLFRSBEMCfZAIZBkgJMoZCZAQwjS8xNwLjaPWLOfQZDZD       How will i write the url?

Comment: How would you use it in a FQL?

Comment: Yes you can specify any date for example today's date is `2012-10-10` so your url would look like: `jarnvags/events?since=2012-10-10` it's in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
Also here's how you do this with your access token: https://graph.facebook.com/jarnvags/events?since=2012-10-10&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBADR1jPcfggJ76VtEvtOHcZBj9AWmKnlPkhfbmmF40gZCmnZB9P5shAZADTLFRSBEMCfZAIZBkgJMoZCZAQwjS8xNwLjaPWLOfQZDZD

Use the `&` sign to concatenate both the query parameters.

Comment: Using FQL: `SELECT eid, name, description, pic_big, start_time, end_time, location FROM event
WHERE creator = 109341359096369
AND eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 109341359096369)
AND start_time >= now()
ORDER BY start_time`

`109341359096369` this is your page id, so if you specify any other page id, it'll return that pages events' and right now the above code filters data using `now()` function which returns current date and time but you can specify the date manually like `'2012-10-10'` instead of `now()`

Comment: I've updated my answer with php code for fetching data using FQL Query.

Comment: I did like this in my Appcelerator titanium code and that worked like a charm!             
    var date = new Date();
    var d  = date.getDate();
    var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    var yy = date.getYear();
    var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
    var evntdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + Titanium.App.Properties.getString("sidnamn") + "/events?since=" + evntdate + "&access_token="+Titanium.Facebook.getAccessToken();

Comment: I have this for my Titanium code but that wont work.           var query='SELECT eid, name, pic_small, description, start_time,end_time, location'
       query+=' FROM event WHERE creator = '+p.page+' AND eid IN (SELECT eid'
       query+=' FROM event_member WHERE uid = '+p.page+' );'
 Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', {query: query},  showEventsResult);      What have i missed?

Comment: You forgot to add semicolons and you've added a single quote after the semicolon at the end which is why it isn't working, try this:
`var query='SELECT eid, name, pic_small, description, start_time,end_time, location';
 query+=' FROM event WHERE creator = ' + p.page + ' AND eid IN (SELECT eid';
 query+=' FROM event_member WHERE uid = ' + p.page + ' )';
 Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', {query: query}, showEventsResult);`

Comment: The semicolons didnt make any difference and when i remove the last single quote at the end i get         [ERROR] Script Error = Parse error (unknown file)
2012-10-10 10:42:06.723 MyApp[4505:19303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '__NSCFDictionary'
terminate called throwing an exception           The first code works fine but i get some events that are in the past.

Comment: When i have this it just works as before (With the old events there)     var query='SELECT eid, name, pic_small, description, start_time,end_time, location';
       query+=' FROM event WHERE creator = '+p.page+' AND eid IN (SELECT eid';
       query+=' FROM event_member WHERE uid = '+p.page+' )';
 Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', {query: query},  showEventsResult);

Comment: Hmm..Weird, Did you try with a date, like `'2012-10-10'` instead of `now()` ?

Comment: Can you try this:
`var query='SELECT eid, name, pic_small, description, start_time,end_time, location'; 
 query+=' FROM event WHERE creator = '+p.page+' AND eid IN (SELECT eid'; 
 query+=' FROM event_member WHERE uid = '+p.page+' ) AND start_time >= "2012-10-10"'; 
 Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', {query: query}, showEventsResult); `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17799/discussion-between-richard-stenstierna-and-sir)