# Facebook Graph API event post results in wrong time

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, timezone, utc, iso8601

I'm posting an event to a Facebook page via the graph api, but when I enter the demanded ISO 8601 timestamps for start and end time I get an unexpected time offset when viewing the event on Facebook.

```
$post_obj['start_time'] = '2013-01-27T12:00+0100';
$post_obj['end_time']   = '2013-01-27T16:00+0100';
```

Facebook event page shows 03:00 - 07:00, which is 9 hours off.

What could possibly have gone wrong?

Thanks,
Thomas

EDIT: When I use -0800 as timezone offset, the time displays correctly.

Comment: Ok, finally found the answer. Everything was alright, but you have to activate "Events Timezone" support in your app settings, which is deactivated for pre-migration apps by default. Only then the ISO8601 gets parsed. The 9 hours offset happened due to the app discarding the TZ from my UTC timestamp and instead posting it in pacific standard time (PST). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell it what is you zone, because timezone is diferent in most of countrys

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$timestamp = strtotime('2012-06-06T16:20:43+0000');
$local_datetime = date('c',$timestamp); 
echo $local_datetime;
```

this work great, check you time zone ant try again

Comment: I thought I do that by adding +0100? This should specify my timezone, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes, but if you do that the funcion will return wrong values, in http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php there is people talking about that mistake, so you can try like the example above

Comment: "$d3 = strtotime("Sun, 26 Oct 0010 12:00:00 +0100"); //But Oct 26 is a Tuesday, NOT a Sunday."

Comment: Still, I don't see how this helps? My timestamps are correct - I tried including the date_default_timezone_set as you suggested, but to no avail. Facebook demands ISO8601 datetime, not some local time.

Comment: $post_obj['start_time'] = '2013-01-27T12:00+0100'; convert this to miliseconds, and try again

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but you're on a wrong path. Your last suggestion doesn't change anything. If I convert to seconds (that's surely what you meant?) and post that to FB, again I get 03:00-07:00 instead of 12:00-16:00 ... my timezone is +0100 and the default_date_timezone is set correctly. The problem must be elsewhere (maybe in the Facebook page's settings?)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/428753260494953/ check this, and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809224/facebook-events-api

Comment: well, most of it had nothing to do with the problem at hand, but at least I found a hint on the developers page about the events timezone setting in facebook apps.

Comment: later night i give you a solution that i implement last year, that i dont have here now and works great, until there try search why is that happening

Comment: Thanks man, not necessary. As I wrote above, I already found the solution. The Facebook app itself was not set up to work with the new Event Timezone flag.